# UUID issue while synchronizing new rule project (Renaming existing project) in Rule Designer workspace

Tags: uuid, rule-engine, ibm-odm

I have to create a new project using the existing branch of another project. In a new workspace, I have imported the existing project, renamed it and synchronized it. When I do that it shows the below issue.

I have tried updating the UUID's for almost every rule, ruleflow, decision operation, deployment configuration, folder. Still, I see the same issue.

[image: Decision Center synchronization error]

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question... I'm assuming you want to know how to synchronize your project (push from Rule Designer to Decision Center). It would help to know what version of ODM you are using -- sync is much worse in older versions. Also, do you have just a single 'main rule project' or are there multiple 'standard rules projects' related to you main rule project? Also, are you using the Rule Governance Framework or not?

Comment: I'm using version 8.10.2

Comment: I'm using version 8.10.2, i'm seeing this issue only coz i'm using existing project in decision center, Steps i've followed 1) created new workspace 2) imported XOM of existing project  3) Imported project from Decision Center (New, Other , Rule Designer from DC ,project , branch) 4) Renamed project 5) tried to  sync and faced above issue 5) updated UUID's for everything (rule, ruleflow, variables, folders, DO, D config)

Comment: I've only main project and i'vent selected governance framework

Comment: Solution: all UUID's need to be updated for entire project before publishing to DC